# wso2 esb endpoint can not be changed

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have some external URL (restful api) to be integrated.

Those URL have different prefixed URL with different parameter at url, for example:

```
www.abc.com/books
www.abc.com/book/11 
www.abc.com/book/11/authors
```

When get response from those invocation, esb needs to convert response from one json format to our standard json format.

I plan to use esb javascript mediator to perform convert operation, but I didn't find any way to attach url parameters.

Any one have any idea?

I have used mediator by java code to implement it, but it is too heavy.

I am also looking into connector for another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a solution by use url template. By this solution, I can change url according to template defined. 
With this solution, I didn't need to write mediator or connector.